# Stop inheritance of a specific CSS class

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have to modify an existing HTML5 app that has two different types of themes.

For example, I have something like this:

```
<body class="theme1 theme2">
    <div id="div1">I'm happy with both themes</div>
    <div id="div2">I just want theme 2</div>
</body>
```

This example is overly simplified. I know that I could just apply theme2 to div2. But the point is that those themes classes are in the body and I cannot "easily" change that.

I naively thought that I could just do something like this in JS:

```
getElementById('div2').classList.remove('theme1');
```

But this does not seem to work. I think that this only work on classes directly applied to the element. I would prefer a "pure CSS" solution anyway.

The info that I find seems related to preventing inheritance of specific properties. In my case, I want to prevent inheritance of any property under the theme1 class for div2 and all its children.

Comment: You can only remove a class from the element that has it. In your case you should remove the class from the body element, or you should add the classes to your divs.

Comment: Use Jquery ! 
$('#div2').parent().removeClass('theme1');

Comment: @4EACH — The goal is to stop a property being inherited into div2 while letting it apply to div1. Removing the class from the parent would stop it being applied to either.

Comment: The example provided is very simplistic. The actual app has many parent elements. I cannot remove classes from the body and body is not the direct parent of the element in question. Also, I am not using jQuery.

Comment: You set the HTML class attribute using `Element.className =` in JavaScript.

Comment: @PHPglue — Using the `classList` interface works fine. The problem has nothing to do with setting the class. That's just an attempt at solving the problem based on a lack of understanding about how CSS and HTML classes interact.

Comment: If adding the property to div2 does not work, use try forcing it with the !important tag in the css descriptor of div2, or by specifying the css property inline on div2 within the html tag. i.e.:  <div id="div2" style="property: property settings"> and this is not optimal but if your layout does not allow you for anything else, it is better than using Javascript. In cases where you need different body properties in different pages you can target the page by id and assign different css classes server side.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Properties are inherited, classes are not.

The only way to stop a property being inherited is to assign a value to that property for the given element.

Comment: Right, so there is no way to tell CSS to stop inheriting all properties set by the class theme1? Using the wildcard (*) perhaps? When I look at the element using the WebKit Developer Tools, it is aware of which class each inherited property belongs to.

Comment: Correct. The property has to have *some* value, and it will be (at least for whatever properties you care about here) `inherit` if it isn't set to something else.

Comment: Okay. This is consistent with what I have been reading so far. Basically, I need to use some class associated to div2 to set a value to all properties that I do not want inherited. I was hoping for a solution that just takes theme2 completely out of the equation for div1 and all its children.

Comment: It doesn't have to be a class. You can use any kind of selector (or combination of selectors) for the ruleset.

Comment: I think that you understand the problem. However, I may not have the proper body of knowledge to fully appreciate your last comment. Could you illustrate in a sample class definition for div2 in my example? (#div2 { what ? })

Comment: Since you haven't specified which properties you want to change the value of, I can't give you an example that solves you specific property. Since you have managed to write rulesets which set properties for the parent element, you clearly know the general form of the body of a ruleset already.

Comment: Okay I understand. This is not an app that I wrote myself from ground up. These themes are rather messy and setting hundreds of properties. I am basically trying to do something in an element pretty deep in the dom of an existing app. I was hoping to just be able to take any properties set by a given class out of the equation. Given this info, I will approach the problem differently. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The code doesn't work because 'theme1' is not a class of div 'div2'.

I don't know of a way to selectively remove the inheritance as you asked. The closest solution I can think of is to use nesting to create a more specific selector and override the undesired styles. Simple example:

```
.theme2 {
    font-style: italic;
}
.theme2 #div2 {
    font-style: normal;
}
```

This would "remove" the italic style from div2. You would have to redefine *all* the undesired styles. From a maintenance standpoint this may or may not be an acceptable solution. But it does solve the problem.

Comment: It solves the problem because the example provided is just a simplistic way to illustrate a concept. The app in question has thousands of elements. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

No, that's not how CSS works. If properties are getting applied to a descendent because of a class on an ancestor, and you cannot change that class or the properties, then you have to override the properties (**via a more specific selector**) that you don't want inherited.

e.g.

```
body.theme2 div { background: #000; }
#div2 { background: transparent; }
```

Comment: The selector doesn't have to be more specific, it just has to match the element you want to change. Specificity rules only apply when multiple rulesets are targeting the same element.

Comment: To be very technical, you're correct - the selector can have the same specificity as the one you are overriding, as long as it appears ***after*** said rule in the stylesheet (hence the ***C*** in CSS). However, I find your comment confusing because the multiple rules in my answer are in fact targeting the same element in the OPs original question.

Comment: In the OP's original question, the problem is that the selector is targeting the *parent* element and he wants to change the properties for *one* of the *child* elements (which are inheriting the values from the parent).

Answer (score 0):

Let's start with some `common.js`:

```
//<![CDATA[
var doc = document, bod = doc.body, IE = parseFloat(navigator.appVersion.split('MSIE')[1]);
bod.className = 'js';
function gteIE(version, className){
  if(IE >= version)bod.className = className;
}
function E(e){
  return doc.getElementById(e);
}
function removeParentClassName(childId, removeClassName){
  var cn = new RegExp('(\s+)?'+removeClassName, 'i'), pn = E(childId).parentNode;
  pn.className = pn.className.replace(cn, '');
}
//]]>
```

Now on your current page:

```
removeParentClassName('div2', 'theme1');
```

Comment: This just seems like a very verbose way to do this: getElementById('div2').parent.classList.remove('theme1'); Of course this would work if my actual implementation was just the simplistic example provided to illustrate the concept. The actual app has many levels of elements between the body and the div that I am trying to reach. The example is not to be taken literally.

Answer (score 0):

One way you could do this with pure CSS would be to set up you CSS rules like so

```
.theme1 .div1,
.theme2 .div1,
.theme1 .div2,
.theme2 .div2 {font-style:normal;} /* apply theme1 and theme2 styles here */

.theme1.theme2 .div2 {font-style:italic;} /* apply theme2 only rules here */
```